# Update a services property in EmberJS without reload

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-simple-auth to handle my authentication. When I login, I'm redirected to my index route. In my application template, I use the `{{outlet` as well as an `{{app-header`

Inside `{{app-header}}` I'm displaying the current user email address. The problem is, this doesn't load, unless I refresh the page. Is there anyway to rerender that component so it will grab the updated information from the **session service**?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just inject the service and use it in your template.

Comment: I do inject the service, but I guess I template doesn't rerender, so it's not loading the new values.